# Problem with sso-login in Django, Error GET /authorize/?token= HTTP/1.1"404 250

Tags: python, django, single-sign-on, idp

I am trying to run simple Django application.
I have already installed simple-sso module in my local app.
I tried but not solved.
Following images tell us that error is occured when i run localserver.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HH7NZ.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NKJPX.png)

Following code is some of "settings.py":

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'ssoLogin.apps.ssoLoginConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'simple_sso.sso_server',
]
ROOT_URLCONF = 'ssoLogin.urls'

# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]

SSO_PRIVATE_KEY='ttVCo7bewsATjEPS7CNHd4tIk1ayyBKb1qbPk5DxWZiK4pvyLZQtnpinjPh6fWr3'

SSO_PUBLIC_KEY='hGtAakAg7Sh3SffSs2obwAAflMuzbbLBUJUHpk6WrFnxhA9b78EHNoTOr0DsDho3'

SSO_SERVER='http://127.0.0.1:8000/server'
```

I used "simple-sso" module correctly according to documentation.
I think everything of config(settings.py) is ok but i don't know urls and views are correct.
Anyway this is my configuration in urls.py.

Following code:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include, re_path
from simple_sso.sso_server.server import Server
from simple_sso.sso_client.client import Client
from django.conf import settings


test_client = Client(settings.SSO_SERVER, settings.SSO_PUBLIC_KEY, settings.SSO_PRIVATE_KEY)
test_server = Server()

urlpatterns = [
    path('polls/', include('polls.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    re_path(r'^server/', include(test_server.get_urls())),
    re_path(r'^client/', include(test_client.get_urls())),
]
```

Server and Client object imported correctly.
I think client is working good but I dont know Server works.
Maybe Server doesn't work correctly.
Need to solve this.

Comment: could you please check with a print(settings.SSO_SERVER) just before test_client=Client(...) if that setting parameter is correct. Sorry for this rather strange idea, but it seems quite at the root of the problem.

Comment: forget the comment, see answer below

Answer (score 0):

1. first error message (original posted question)

SSO_SERVER needs a slash at the end:

```
SSO_SERVER='http://127.0.0.1:8000/server/'
```

2. subsequent error message (from comment below):

Root cause is the coexistance of server and client in one app.

when you request  /client/ there will be a request to get a token:

(see https://github.com/divio/django-simple-sso/blob/master/simple_sso/sso_client/client.py)

```
class LoginView(View):
    ...
    def get(self, request):
        ...
        request_token = self.client.get_request_token(redirect_to)
        ...
```

which will built an url from

```
    SSO_SERVER='http://127.0.0.1:8000/server/' + reverse('simple-sso-request-token')
```

because you have the server in your server urls, reverse('simple-sso-request-token') returns "/server/request-token/"

Together you get

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/server/server/request-token/
```

I am not sure if the path name "simple-sso-request-token" is needed somewhere else - if not, you could just "overwrite" it by adding a line with a dummy view to the urls.py just to make the reverse result change:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('polls/', include('polls.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    re_path(r'^server/', include(test_server.get_urls())),
    re_path(r'^client/', include(test_client.get_urls())),
    path("request-token/", some_dummy_view , name='simple-sso-request-token'),  # this is only to force reverse("simple-sso-request-token") to return "request-token/"
]
```

(reverse() returns the last path in the urlpatterns list)

This will lead to

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/server/request-token/
```

hope there is no further error messages

Comment: If  i do this. Another error is appeared.

Comment: WebserviceError at /client/
b'<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html lang="en">\n<head>\n  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">\n  <title>Page not found at /server/server/request-token/</title>\n  <meta name="robots" content="NONE,NOARCHIVE">\n  <style type="text/css">\n    html * { padding:0; margin:0; }\n    body * { padding:10px 20px; }\n    body * * { padding:0; }\n    body { font:small sans-serif; background:#eee; color:#000; }\n    body>div { border-bottom:1px solid #ddd; }\n    h1 { font-weight:normal; margin-bottom:.4em; }\n    h1 span { font-size:60%; ...........

Comment: And this is from console [18/Jan/2023 10:18:12] "GET /client/ HTTP/1.1" 500 109777

Comment: see updated answer above